# Hibernate cannot find table

Tags: database, hibernate, jpa

I started a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse an turned it into a JPA project using Hibernate as the persistence provider. Then I used the JPA tools of Eclipse to generate Entities from the tables, which also worked fine. But when I try to persist an object of my class "Person", I receive the error 'Table "Person" not found'. The table is named exactly like this in the database (PostgreSQL) and the Entity Manager is also active (isOpen returns true). I also tried different namings (uppercase, explicitly quoted etc) of the table in the database and of the name attribute in the annotation to be sure it's not that kind of problem.

```
@Entity
@Table(schema="public", name="Person")
@NamedQuery(name="Person.findAll", query="SELECT p FROM Person p")
public class Person implements Serializable {
...
```

> Table "Person" not found; SQL statement:
> insert into public.Person ([columns]) values ([values])[42102-197]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: postgresql is case sensative by default. Check for table name ‘person’ in the darabase.

Comment: I wish that would have been it, but it made no difference at all

Comment: Looks like I didn't get how the auto-generation of primary keys works. I set up IDENTITY to create a new key for the column id for each data set and set the value of the column to null. Of course this must not be, because it's set to "NOT NULL" in the database